# Angular NX 17 Upgrade - nx/angular no longer exports 'NxModule'

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I have completed running migrations to Angular 17, and my in my **app.module.ts** file I have an import for **NxModule**:

```
import { NxModule } from '@nx/angular';
```

and I have **NxModule.forRoot()** added in my imports:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ShellModule,
    NxModule.forRoot(),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducer, {
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true,
      },
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 30,
      logOnly: environment.production,
    connectInZone: true}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: StsConfigLoader,
        useFactory: httpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
    CommonServicesModule.forRoot(),
    CommonUiModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  ....
```

The previous version of Nx included the following 2 exports in
**node_modules@nrwl\angular\index.d.ts**:

```
export { DataPersistence, fetch, navigation, optimisticUpdate, pessimisticUpdate, } from './src/runtime/nx/data-persistence';
export { NxModule } from './src/runtime/nx/nx.module';
```

However, **NxModule** was deprecated since v14 and it was removed in v15.

This is what the Angular intelligence shows when I hover over the import:

```
Module '"@nx/angular"' has no exported member 'NxModule'
```

The documentation on the Nx site just provides the following information:

- *This option will be removed in a future version of Nx. Please switch to using --parent instead.*

I am not understanding what *"Please switch to using --parent instead"* actually means, and all other searches for NxModule deprecation have not provided any direction for how to resolve this.

How do I go about or what changes do I need to resolve this error?

Comment: try to remove node_modules directory and run `npm i`

Comment: I have done a fresh install to create a new node_modules folder and source, and that does not resolve the issue. It is looking for an export that no longer exists in @nx/angular.  I found this thread (https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/17181) but it does not address the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NxModule was deprecated in version 14 and removed in version 15 of Nx. To address the error you're facing after upgrading to Angular 17, you should remove the NxModule import and its usage from your app.module.ts. Instead, if you were using NxModule for data persistence operations, you can directly use data persistence operators from `@ngrx/router-store/data-persistence`.

To resolve the error due to the deprecation of `NxModule` in your Angular application, follow these steps:

1. **Remove NxModule Import and Usage**:

   - Remove the `NxModule` import and its invocation from your `app.module.ts`. Since `NxModule` is deprecated and no longer exists in Nx version 15 and beyond, it should not be used.
   - For example, delete the lines:

     ```js
     import { NxModule } from '@nx/angular';
     // And in your @NgModule imports array
     NxModule.forRoot(),
     ```
2. **Use Data Persistence Operators from NgRx**:

   - If you were using `NxModule` for data persistence features, you should replace it with the equivalent operators from `@ngrx/router-store/data-persistence`.
   - As suggested in a [GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/17181), you can import these operators directly. For example:

     ```js
     import { fetch, navigation, optimisticUpdate, pessimisticUpdate } from '@ngrx/router-store/data-persistence';
     ```
3. **Refer to Nx Documentation**:

   - For more details on how to use Nx with Angular and for up-to-date practices, refer to the [Nx and Angular CLI documentation](https://nx.dev/using-nx/nx-and-angular).
4. **Update Other Usages of Nx**:

   - If you are using other features from Nx, ensure they are updated according to the latest version. Nx has changed its package naming from `@nrwl` to `@nx`, and it is essential to use the correct package names.
   - The [Nx documentation](https://nx.dev) provides comprehensive guidance on using the latest features and best practices in Nx.

Answer (score 0):

You have some example on the schematics schema [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/angular/src/generators/ngrx/schema.json)

```
  "examples": [
    {
      "command": "nx g @nx/angular:ngrx --root --parent=apps/my-app/src/app/app.module.ts --facade=false placeholder",
      "description": "Add root ngrx configration to the `my-app` application"
    },
    {
      "command": "nx g @nx/angular:ngrx --parent=libs/my-lib/src/lib/my-lib.module.ts --facade=true --root=false users",
      "description": "Add a `users` state with a facade to the `my-lib` library. It will be tracked under the default `+state` folder in the lib"
    },
    {
      "command": "nx g @nx/angular:ngrx --parent=apps/my-app/src/app/app.config.ts --root",
      "description": "Add a root state configuration to `my-app` when `my-app` uses Standalone APIs"
    },
    {
      "command": "nx g @nx/angular:ngrx --parent=libs/my-lib/src/lib.routes.ts users",
      "description": "Add a `users` feature state to the Route definition of a library using Standalone APIs"
    }
  ],
```